# Why isn't my .htaccess 301 redirect working?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect this URL to a different subdomain but am getting a 404.

Need to redirect:

www.dustystrings.com/instrumentbuilding / XYZ

To here:

manufacturing.dustystrings.com/instrumentbuilding / XYZ

I have www.dustystrings.com on one server, and manufacturing.dustystrings.com on another server (necessity).

Basically, I want to redirect all www.dustystrings.com/instrumentbuilding/ queries to manufacturing.dustystrings.com/instrumentbuilding/

What's the right .htacess 301 code to do this? (Apache server)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dustystrings.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^.*/instrumentbuilding/(.*)$ http://manufacturing.dustystrings.com/instrumentbuilding/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to www using htaccess redirect

Create a .htaccess file with the below code, it will ensure that all requests coming in to domain.com will get redirected to www.domain.com 
The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website (i.e the same directory where your index file is placed)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Please REPLACE domain.com and www.newdomain.com with your actual domain name.
```

Note* This .htaccess method of redirection works ONLY on Linux servers having the Apache Mod-Rewrite moduled enabled.